# Android keyboard *only* for typing emoji

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard, emoji

I'm looking for an **Android keyboard** whose sole purpose is for typing emoji. So, it doesn't need all those bells and whistles such as predictive typing, or gesture typing, or spellchecking. Just emojis.

*Preferably* a lightweight one that does not consume too much memory and storage.

*Preferably* with a key to quickly switch back to another keyboard (like the AOSP Keyboard; holding down spacebar shows the selection box to change languages, but *also* to change into a different keyboard). This feature is NOT necessary though. I can always pull down the notification tray to choose a different IME.

Comment: If the keyboard also came with regular text input, would that be ok?

Answer (score 1):

Getting **emoji** on Android devices used to be tricky, but there are several ways to add emoji to just **about any device**. **First** determine your **Android version**. And follow the steps that define how to get emoji on Android, in given below link which might help you:

http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Emoji-on-Android

If you are not satisfied with this link then click on the link

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&hl=en

to get **Swiftkey Keyboard + emoji** on your android. **SwiftKey Keyboard** is a ***free,*** award-winning keyboard app for Android  that learns from you, delivering the **best next-word prediction**, **smarter autocorrect,** support for over **800 emoji** (emoticons) & emoji **prediction**.